The Kobayashi distance function of the unit disc is exactly the distance function of the Poincaré metric
Background and definitions:

Denote by $(\Delta, h_{0})$ the unit disc in $\mathbb{C}$ equipped with the Poincaré metric
$$h_{0}=\frac{d z \otimes d \bar{z}}{(1-|z|^{2})^{2}}.$$
which is complete Kähler and has negative constant curvature. The distance function $d_{0}$ of $h_{0}$ is given by
$$d_{0}(0, z)=\int_0^1|\alpha'(t)|_{h_0}dt=\ln \left(\frac{1+|z|}{1-|z|}\right),\quad{\rm where}~~\alpha(t)=tz.$$
Let $M^{n}$ be a complex manifold. Given $p, q \in M$, consider a finite set of holomorphic maps $f_{i}: \Delta \rightarrow M, 1 \leq i \leq l$, such that there are points $z_{1}, \ldots, z_{l} \in \Delta$ with
$$f_{1}(0)=p, f_{1}\left(z_{1}\right)=f_{2}(0), f_{2}\left(z_{2}\right)=f_{3}(0), \ldots, f_{l-1}\left(z_{l-1}\right)=f_{l}(0), f_{l}\left(z_{l}\right)=q.$$
We will call such a set a chain of holomorphic discs from $p$ to $q$. The length of the chain is defined by $\sum_{i=1}^{l} d_{0}\left(0, z_{i}\right)$.
The Kobayashi distance between $p$ and $q$, denoted by $d_{k}(p, q)$, is defined by the infimum of the length of any (finite) chain of holomorphic discs from $p$ to $q$. It's a pseudo distance. By the definition and the classical Schwarz-Pick lemma, we have $d_k=d_0$ for the unit disc $\Delta$ itself.

Schwarz-Pick lemma only describes the behavior of holomorphic function $f$ of the unit disc that satisfy $f(0)=0$, but we are not clear about the behavior of function that $f(0)\neq0$. For example, if given $z,w\in\Delta$ with $z\neq0\neq w$, then how do we obtain $d_k(z,w)=d_0(z,w)$ by using the Schwarz-Pick lemma? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDITED: (A property about Kobayashi distance)
One 'built-in' property about this pseudo distance function is its decreasing property under holomorphic maps. That is, if $f: M \rightarrow N$ is a holomorphic map between two complex manifolds, then for any $p, q \in M$, it holds
$$d_{k}(f(p), f(q)) \leq d_{k}(p, q)$$
since any chain of holomorphic discs from $p$ to $q$ is mapped under $f$ to a chain of holomorphic discs from $f(p)$ to $f(q)$, thus has length no less than $d_{k}(f(p), f(q))$.
In particular, if $f \in {\rm Aut}(M)$, then by applying the decreasing property to both $f$ and $f^{-1}$, we know that $f^{*} d_{k}=d_{k}$, that is, the Kobayashi distance $d_{k}$ is an invariant (pseudo) distance function.

Classic Schwarz-Pick lemma: If $f:\Delta\to\Delta$ is holomorphic, then
$$\frac{|f'(z)|}{1-|f(z)|^2}\leq\frac1{1-|z|^2}.$$
Proof. Let $a\in\Delta$,
$$g(z):=\frac{z+a}{1+\bar az},\quad h(z):=\frac{z-f(a)}{1-\overline{f(a)}z},\quad F:=h\circ f\circ g,$$
then $F:\Delta\to\Delta$ is holomorphic, $F(0)=0$ and
$$F'(0)=h'(f(a))f'(a)g'(0)=\frac{1-|a|^2}{1-|f(a)|^2}f'(a).$$
By Schwarz lemma, $|F'(0)|\leq1$.

$$\frac{|f'(z)|}{1-|f(z)|^2}\leq\frac1{1-|z|^2}$$
means $|f_*(v)|_{h_0}\leq|v|_{h_0}$, i.e. $f^*h_0\leq h_0$, so $d_0(f(p),f(q))\leq d_0(p,q)$, $\forall p,q\in\Delta$. Thus
$$\sum_{i=1}^{l} d_{0}\left(0, z_{i}\right)\geq\sum_{i=1}^{l} d_{0}\left(f_i(0), f_i(z_{i})\right)\geq d_0(p,q),$$
which means $d_k\geq d_0$. On the other hand, take $f={\rm Id}_\Delta$, we have $d_k\leq d_0$. So $d_k=d_0$.
